# At what x does this series converge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

At what $x$ does the series $\sum_{0}^{\infty} (1-(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}))^n $ and prove for those $x$ it converges to $f(x)=\frac{3}{2+ \sqrt{x}}$ .

I know the general term must tend to zero in order to have a chance for convergence. So for $x=9$, I get zero. How do I continue?

Comment: I guess it would be better to show some effort from your side before posting any more questions.

Comment: "I don't know where to start" is not a valid comment here. We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: im trying for an hour now. i only got that x=9 in order to have the general term 0 so it may be converge

Comment: You've been on this site for three years. You should be familiar with the rules described in the [help center.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: i know about that.Im just in a bad day and in a hurry sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: $\frac3{2+\sqrt{9}}$ is not zero. Did you mean (third version by now) $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}3\right)^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a geometric series of the form $$\sum a^n $$
which, you should know, converges
$$\iff |a|<1$$
the sum is then $\frac {1}{1-a} $.

so, your series converges
$$\iff |1-\frac {\sqrt {x}}{3}|<1$$
$$\iff -1 <1-\frac {\sqrt {x}}{3}<1$$
$$\iff 0 <\frac {\sqrt {x}}{3}<2$$
$$\iff 0<\sqrt{x}<6$$
$$\iff 0 <x <36$$

Comment: @how do i prove it converges to the $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis it converges to $3/\sqrt {x} $

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-a}$ for $|a|<1$.